# Serialize JSON ListView

Tags: c#, winforms

Подскажите, как исправить ошибку, всё никак не получается.

> System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: 'The data contract type 'System.Windows.Forms.ListView' is not serializable with DataContractJsonSerializer because the data member 'Padding' is duplicated in its type hierarchy.'

```
public void Serialize<T>(T list, string path)
{
    var jsonFormatter = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(T));
    using (var file = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create))
    {
        jsonFormatter.WriteObject(file, list);
    }
}
```

Возможно кто-то подскажет, может у вас уже есть метод сериализации и десериализации, чтобы можно было передавать обьекты любого типа?

Comment: Вам обязательно использовать `DataContractJsonSerializer`? Почему вы взяли именно его? Какие требования у вас выдвигаются к содержимому классов и формату сериализации? Опишите подробнее, мы посоветуем.

Comment: DataContractJsonSerializer взято из примера, видимо я не тот инструмент использую.?

Comment: Сериализаторов в .NET существует несколько: бинарные, xml, json... Если брать только json, то есть ещё [JavaScriptSerializer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer?view=netframework-4.8). А также очень популярна библиотека json.net.

Comment: По условиям задачи требуеться, добавить в ListView обьект, чем посоветуете воспользьзоваться для сирилизации и десирилизации ListView, не прибегая к созданию стороннего класа(типа FilmCollection). Возможно ссылку на почитать?

Comment: _ добавить в ListView обьект_ - вот этот объект и сериализуйте. Если объектов добавляется несколько, то используйте любую стандартную коллекцию для их хранения, например, `List<T>`. Эту коллекцию и (де)сериализуйте.

Comment: Нашел решение, очень подробно все расписано. Спасибо за помощь.

Comment: У _всех_ контролов WinForms _десятки_ свойств. Соответственно, если тупо сериализовать `ListView`, то все эти свойства будут сохраняться (шрифты, цвета, выделения и пр.). Причём многие свойства сами по себе сложные объекты, которые тоже содержат десятки свойств. В итоге объём сохраняемых данных чудовищно распухнет. _Никогда_ не сохраняйте GUI-объекты (если конечно, вы не пишете GUI-редактор). Храните данные бизнес-логики.

Comment: Спасибо, уяснил

Comment: По факту я должен делать так: Employe emp = new Employe(). Потом добавлять в ListView и добавлять к себе в List<>, а потом делать, что хочу верно понимаю? (Это не будет расценено как код дупликейт?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ошибка тебе говорит что `'System.Windows.Forms.ListView'` сериализовать невозможно.

Сериализуй не сам компонент формы, а его `datasource`, в котором хранятся данные для ListView.
Например, храни данные для `ListView` в каком-то `List<>` (присвоив его в `SomeListView.DataSource`) и уже этот лист пытайся сериализовать.

---

UPD: если нету в `ListView`DataSource то используй аналогичный компонент, например DataGrid. Там точно есть DataSource.

Comment: Ну я думал, что ListView это и есть список и создавать какой-то дополнительно будет просто кодом дупликейтом. Я уже делал отдельно Класс, в который выносил List<Films> и его серилизовал, но тогда в коде получаеться, все делать приходиться в двойне(Добавить в свой List, а потом добавить в ListView, удалить из своего, удалить из ListView)

Comment: подключи `List<Films>` в `SomeListView.DataSource` вот так: `SomeListView.DataSource = instanceOfList` и ничего дублировать не нужно будет. Ты просто неправильно работаешь с `ListView`. :)

Comment: понял, сейчас буду практиковать

Comment: .DataSource у меня отсутствует, возможно это свойство из WPF (VS2017)

Comment: Странно. Ладно, тогда подсмотри реализацию биндинга вот здесь: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10008/Data-binding-a-ListView Или замени листВью на другой компонет. Там остальные должны поддерживать ДатаСоурс. ДатаГрид точно поддерживает.

Comment: Если ответ помог, принято отдать голос за ответ и отметить его как правильным. Удачного обучения :)